# Scoping Issue with PHP Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to solve this problem where I have a unique array of values within a specific range. Take this scenario: Generate a fixed value array (90) with unique entries. If you find a duplicate, remove, reindex, and fill the void. I'm running into the problem that conditional statements do not allow you to interact with an array outside of it's scope. I'm aware of `array_unique` but it doesn't refill those gaps, just makes them. How do I refill those gaps?

EDIT: This was a noobish question about scoping. A simple `while` loop demonstrated that if conditional statements can modify variables outside of it's scope.
?>

Comment: " I'm running into the problem that conditional statements do not allow you to interact with an array outside of it's scope" this I don't get at all. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but you can always reiterate over the array once the duplicateds have been removed and reindex it if that is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Making sure I understand this - you don't care for the array key elements?

You could still use array_unique();

```
// $array(); is already defined with elements in it
$temp_array = array_unique($array);
if ( !empty ( $temp_array ) ) {
   unset($array);
   $array = array();
   foreach ( $temp_array as $t ) {
      array_push($array, $t);
   }
}
```

You'd probably want to put a clause in there stopping it if it goes over 90 elements.

Comment: Wait, if you define an array (or any variable) inside of a conditional, doesn't it have it's own scope, so the array would only be accessible inside of that `if` statement?

Comment: In this case, the only time the you won't be able to get into the the if statement is if your original array is empty.

Comment: What I'm asking is if I do something like this `if(array_search ($array_value , $array)){ $array[$key] = $unique_value;}` would work, if that makes any sense.